# How to know current interfaceOrientation in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit, uiinterfaceorientation

Now that `interfaceOrientation` propery in `UIViewController` is deprecated, what is the recommended way to detect current device orientation?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

Pay attention that `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` is **not exactly** like your application rotation. The docs:

> **Discussion:**
>   The value of the property is a constant that indicates the current orientation of the device. This value represents the physical orientation of the device and may be different from the current orientation of your application’s user interface. See UIDeviceOrientation for descriptions of the possible values.

I would check if the statusBarOrientation works.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift you can get it with

`let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation`

Answer (score 2):

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation works unless you are calling it from

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

which PREDATES the change to the new statusBarOrientation

so if you are using viewWillTransitionToSize to update
device based on orientation (rather than size classes) you are screwed
and have to use something like this

```
extension UIViewController {
    public var orientation : UIInterfaceOrientation? {
        let orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
        var converted : UIInterfaceOrientation!
        // UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation is trash cause it lags (being set to the value predating the transition reported by viewWillTransitionToSize)
        switch orientation {
        case .Portrait: // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
            converted = .Portrait
        case .PortraitUpsideDown: // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
            converted = .PortraitUpsideDown
        case .LandscapeLeft: // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
            converted = .LandscapeLeft
        case .LandscapeRight: // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
            converted = .LandscapeRight
        default:
            // let the caller do the dirty dancing with the status bar orientation or whatever
            return nil
        }
        return converted
    }
}
```

Which you'd use like so:

```
    // willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) is deprecated.
    // thusly I have to use the size classes method and compute interface orientation from the device orientation
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        guard let converted = orientation else {
            //            alert("something else that I do not [need to] handle")
            return
        }
        if converted.isLandscape {
            adjustViewsForOrientation(converted, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        } else if converted.isPortrait {
            adjustViewsForOrientation(converted, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        }
    }
```

I do not know how to get out of this brave new world (of suck) short
of convincing appple of undeprecating willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
the same way they did with autoresizingMask
(except they had the sense to not deprecate autoresizingMask ;-)

that or injecting interfaceorientation as a third parameter into the
viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)

Answer (score 0):

for iPad

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Comment: But I'm curious if that's still the same as `UIInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: No it is not. There is an ugly way that sucks that warranted a separate answer cause it's too large for a comment.